# Wordpress AJAX File Upload

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, file-upload

I am having trouble saving the uploaded file to the Wordpress database:

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="portfolio-container">
<form method="post" id="genealogist-code-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        <span class="col-xs-1 check <?php if($locked1 == 0){ echo 'fa fa-times-circle-o'; } else { echo 'fa fa-check-circle'; } ?> "></span>
        <h1 class="col-xs-6">1. Genealogist's Code</h1>
        <?php if($locked1 == 0){ ?>
            <label for="file-field" class="btn add-file-btn col-xs-2 text-center">Add File</label>

            <input type="file" name="file" id="file-field" style="display:none;">
    <!-- </div>
    <div> -->
            <input type="submit" id="1" class="col-xs-2 app-upload-btn">
            <button class="col-xs-1 delete upload-1-delete"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

$('.app-upload-btn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $current = $(this);

    // var file_data = $('.file-field').prop('files')[0];
    var file_data = $('#file-field').val();

    var strconfirm = confirm('Are you sure? This cannot be undone.');

    if (strconfirm == true && file_data != undefined) {
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {
                'action': 'save_portfolio',
                'portfolio_num': $(this).attr('id'),
                // 'form_data': form_data
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                $current.siblings(".check").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
                $current.css("display", "none");
                $current.siblings('.delete').css("display", "none");
                $current.siblings('.add-file-btn').css("display", "none");
            },
            error: function( error ) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        })
    } else {
        alert('please reupload.');
    }
})
```

Here is the PHP code where I am having trouble accessing the uploaded file:

```
function bcg_portfolio_submission() {

$user = wp_get_current_user();
$portfolio_num = $_POST['portfolio_num'];
$portfolio_locked = 'portfolio_locked_'. $portfolio_num;

$form_data = print_r($_FILES['form_data']);

update_user_meta( $user->ID, $portfolio_locked, true);
wp_send_json_success($form_data);

die();

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_portfolio', 'bcg_portfolio_submission' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_portfolio', 'bcg_portfolio_submission');
```

I'd like to send a data object to be accessed via PHP. Can I just add data : form_data as an element of the object? How do I access this form data in php? Do I use the global $_FILE variable? If so, can you provide an example of what this would look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below answer in Js and PHP code, it is worked for me for upload file from ajax call.

```
// Javascript code //

var formdata = new FormData();
 var file = jQuery("#file-field")[0].files[0];
 formdata.append('action', 'ajax_call_function');
 formdata.append('file', file);
 formdata.append('nonce', nonce);
jQuery.ajax({
        url:ajaxurl,  // your ajax URL
        data: formdata,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',                   
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(response)
        {
            //console.log('check respose');       
        }
```

in PHP code.

you can get path in ajax call-back function at PHP side by global value.

```
$filename=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: make sure you are using nonce, i have added it in answer, if you are not using then remove it from java script code.and what is console / PHP error you are getting?

Comment: I think the issue is that I am sending a data object to php. How can I add the formdata to an object?

Comment: This is what I need: `data: {
                'action': 'save_portfolio',
                'portfolio_num': $(this).attr('id'),
                // 'form_data': form_data
            }`

Comment: replace var file_data = $('#file-field').val(); with  var file_data= jQuery("#file-field")[0].files[0];

Comment: add formdata.append('action', 'save_portfolio');
 formdata.append('file', file_data); in your JS code.

Comment: replace data: {
                'action': 'save_portfolio',
                'portfolio_num': $(this).attr('id'),
                // 'form_data': form_data
            },

Comment: with  data: formdata, in your ajax-call in js

Answer (score 0):

To upload `image` using `ajax`, you have to create a `form` like:

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append('file', file_data);
// In the same way append all the html elements value in the form
```

now send this form in `data` like:

```
data : form_data
```

Try with this approach.

You can get the formdata values in php like:

```
$_FILES['file']     // for file
$_REQUEST['index']  // for other html elements
```

Comment: Also, I'm sending a data object. Can I just add `data : form_data` as an element of the object? How do I access this form data in php? Do I use the global $_FILE variable? If so, can you provide an example of what this would look like?

Comment: The form_data object is empty.

Comment: Check these two links: https://github.com/pandeyz/File-upload-using-Ajax/blob/master/index.php and https://github.com/pandeyz/File-upload-using-Ajax/blob/master/upload.php

Comment: Thanks for the links, but I think the issue is I need to add the form_data variable to a data object. How can I achieve this like in the OP?